# Taylor series of $\frac{1}{1+(1-x)^{-n}}$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I am trying to find a formula for the Taylor series of $\frac{1}{1+(1-x)^{-n}}$ around $x=0$ (in an explicit sum form). Since the series of $(1-x)^{-n}$ is known it feels like it should be possible to do but I am not sure how.

Comment: You need to specify where you want the Taylor Series at. If you want it centered at $x=1$ then it's not difficult. If you mean at $x=0$ then you should edit the question to say so.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: It seems like the closed form of a geometric series

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$\frac{1}{1+(1-x)^{-n}}=\frac{(1-x)^{n}}{1+(1-x)^{n}}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k(n)\,x^k$$
$$(1-x)^{n}=\left(1+(1-x)^{n} \right)\times \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k(n)\,x^k \right)$$